# Displaying Json with multiple array inside Listview

Tags: arrays, listview, react-native

I'm new in react native and I'm having trouble with displaying all the json data in a listview with multiple arrays. I need to save the data using asyncStorage. The json data is from MQTT. Is it possible to use multiple map iterator inside return in react native?

here is my code for displaying the JSon in my listview:

```
<ListView 
   enableEmptySections={true}
   dataSource{this.state.ds.cloneWithRows
   (this.props.quotes)}
   renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
/>
```

here is my render row:

```js
renderRow(rowData) {
   return (
        <TouchableOpacity>
           <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text style={styles.description}>
                    {rowData.id}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.description}>
                    {rowData.a}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
}
```

And here is my JSON Data:

```
{
  "sample":[
       {
            "id": 1,
            "Sam1":[
            {
              "a": 1,
              "b": 2, 
              "arr": [
                   {
                     "b": 1,
                     "c": 2,
                   }    
                 ]
            },
         ]
       }
  ]
}
```

I have 3 arrays how can I display the 2nd and third array in my listview? 
Thanks for answering :)

cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just map over those sub arrays. Here's an example using your JSON. It might make more sense if you provided more realistic JSON, but here goes.

```
rowData.Sam1.map(sam => {
   <Text>{sam.a}</Text>
   sam.arr.map(a => {
     <Text>{a.b}</Text>
   }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are mapping an actual array. Whatever you are mapping is undefined